# rc.local isn't starting on boot

Tags: linux, raspbian

```
● rc-local.service - /etc/rc.local Compatibility
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/rc-local.service; enabled-runtime; vendor preset: enabled)
    Drop-In: /usr/lib/systemd/system/rc-local.service.d
             └─debian.conf
             /etc/systemd/system/rc-local.service.d
             └─ttyoutput.conf
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2023-02-09 22:15:36 PST; 13min ago
       Docs: man:systemd-rc-local-generator(8)
    Process: 513 ExecStart=/etc/rc.local start (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)
        CPU: 9ms

Feb 09 22:15:36 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Starting /etc/rc.local Compatibility...
Feb 09 22:15:36 raspberrypi systemd[513]: rc-local.service: Failed to execute /etc/rc.local: Exec format error
Feb 09 22:15:36 raspberrypi systemd[513]: rc-local.service: Failed at step EXEC spawning /etc/rc.local: Exec format>
Feb 09 22:15:36 raspberrypi systemd[1]: rc-local.service: Control process exited, code=exited, status=203/EXEC
Feb 09 22:15:36 raspberrypi systemd[1]: rc-local.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Feb 09 22:15:36 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Failed to start /etc/rc.local Compatibility.
```

~
~
~
~
~
~

and here is the rc.local file

```
python3 /home/sheepify/Desktop/main.py &
exit 0
```

i am using raspberry pi os on the pi 4 model b 8gb ram

Comment: If someone's missing the rc.local compatibility package just run sudo apt-get install systemd  -- Then you can run sudo systemctl status rc-local or sudo systemctl start rc-local

Answer (score 5):

Make sure you have this at the top of /etc/rc.local

`#!/bin/sh -e`

Make sure you have this at the end of /etc/rc.local

`exit 0`

Answer (score 2):

```
rc-local.service: Failed to execute /etc/rc.local: Exec format error
```

Since there is no shebang line (`#!` at the beginning of `/etc/rc.local`), it looks like the kernel has attempted to run it as a binary executable, and that has obviously not worked out too well.

Unlike shells, `systemd` does not auto-detect scripts that do not have the shebang line present: it just runs the `exec()` system call on whatever is on the `ExecStart=` line of the service definition.

If you absolutely want to use `rc.local`, change it to:

```
#!/bin/sh -e
python3 /home/sheepify/Desktop/main.py &
exit 0
```

and make sure it's marked as executable (`sudo chmod a+x /etc/rc.local`).